# Getting started with animations

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create an animation in which a circle will be containing some text or image inside it, when user will tap on circle, the circle will reveal its child circles, which will be containing some details in text form. This is something similar to discovr app http://discovr.info/. I am totally a newbie in graphics and animation world. I have read several post & documents like where to start with animations, opengl, core animation, cocos2d etc, but still don't know how should I start working on this application. I will be really grateful if you can help me in getting stating up this project. Please also tell me where else I should look for resources.

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great start for CoreAnimation (if you don't want to read whole Apple documentation) could be this tutorials by Mike Nachbaur (4 parts):

[Animating Interfaces with Core Animation: Part 1](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-1)

[Animating Interfaces with Core Animation: Part 2](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-2)

[Animating Interfaces with Core Animation: Part 3](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-3)

[Animating Interfaces with Core Animation: Part 4](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-4)

When new iOS trainees in my job are starting to learn CA I often give them this tutorials because everything is clearly explained there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the awesome reply, It will take me around 5 days to study all this. Then I will be rocking my app :). Fantastic resource.

Answer (score 1):

There are some great [guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514) in the Apple developer library.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have already seen this, it will take too much time to study this whole document(book), I want to do it in shorter time. What should I do :( ...

Comment: You can check out the graphics and animation tutorials [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).